# Google Calendar API timeZone attribute

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a list of time zones that I am using, and I want to pass them to google calendar rather than converting them to offsets at runtime. I am already using a match table for these time zones, and I am adding the timezone offset at the end of the "dateTime" attribute for each of these timezones.

```
CET
Europe/Prague
US/Eastern
PST
EST
US/Pacific
CTT
Asia/Tokyo
CST
Asia/Taipei
Europe/London
Europe/Amsterdam
Europe/Belgrade
America/Montreal
Australia/Melbourne
Europe/Oslo
Europe/Berlin
Europe/Zurich
Asia/Novosibirsk
Asia/Hong_Kong
Asia/Shanghai
ROK
Asia/Jerusalem
America/Fortaleza
IST
America/Belem
America/New_York
```

The problem is, this list will only continue to grow, and what I am asking is if there is a way for google calendar to interpret these timezone names as offsets to UTC. I have a sample of the JSON I use:

```
{
  "Event" : {
    "description" : "Out of office. Reason: Doctor_visit. Status: APPROVED.",
    "end" : {
      "dateTime" : "2016-11-16T09:00:00+0200"
      "timeZone" : "Europe/Prague"
    },
    "start" : {
      "dateTime" : "2016-11-16T12:00:00+0200"
       "timeZone" : "Europe/Prague"
    },
    "summary" : "Out of office"
  },
  "parameters" : {
    "calendarId" : "xxx@group.calendar.google.com"
  }
}
```

Instead of the "+0200" offset, I am asking if I can pass in "timeZone" : "Europe/Prague" to be interpreted somehow. I have tried putting an offset of "+0000" and passing in the timezone name to the "timeZone" attribute, or passing in "+0000" and a "timeZone" attribute interpreted as "UTC+2:00", but the only way it seems to work for me is if I interpret the timezone at runtime and add an offset at the end of the "dateTime" attribute in the format above.

I am using Dell Boomi to communicate with the calendar API. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Google calendars timezones are internal you cant change them if you want to add an event as stated in the documentation for [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.

You must convert it to the correct format when you insert it.  YOu may want to consider adding this as a feature request [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)