# Why Google Calendar API ignoring the timeZone parameter?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to do this HTTP request:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

And I'm trying to use the timeZone parameter but googleapis responding with default calendar time zone, why?

Here is the example of request:
 https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/kn3uefbt9tue2q8cgu82vbm1q0@group.calendar.google.com/events?timeMin=2019-06-02T20:37:03Z&timeZone=Europe/Moscow&key=${key}

I also tried timeZone=GMT+03:00 – same result.

I tried [**Try this API**](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and it is also not working for me – 
[image]

Any ideas what I am do wrong?

Comment: I am not really sure what's going on with this error, but I've observed the same. When I am trying to use the [**Events: list**](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method the timeZone returns was same as what it is specified in the [**CalendarList: list**](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method. You can refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597988/google-calendar-api-timezone-attribute), if you think this is something that Google needs to change or to look up on.